How to add custom handling for different log levels in Winston
I am using Winston for logging in my application. I want to be able to feed errorType and errorSubtype parameters to my logger.error calls without affecting the other log methods, like so:
logger.error("validation_error", "user_age_validation_error", "User provided invalid age!")
Should print
{"message": "User provided invalid age!",
"errorType": "validation_error",
"errorSubtype": "user_age_validation_error"}

Is it possible to configure the Winston logger to enable this? This is my logger definition:
logger = createLogger({
    levels: config.syslog.levels,
    format: format.combine(
      format.timestamp(),
      format.errors({ stack: true }),
      format.json()
    ),
    transports: [
      new transports.Console(),
    ],
  });


IMO, the easiest option would be to use the meta param of the logger.error method. So, you can do something like logger.error('User provided invalid age!', {   errorType: 'validation_error',   errorSubtype: 'user_age_validation_error', });. This will print {"errorSubtype":"user_age_validation_error","errorType":"validation_error","level":"error","message":"User provided invalid age!","timestamp":"2024-09-26T14:44:45.486Z"}
